# Spring Boot / JPA / H2 - Table not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

My application uses an embedded H2 with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
   # url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    url: jdbc:h2:./db/app_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
    username: user
    password: pass
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

The database is accessed using Spring Data in the simplest form, i.e.:

```
public interface AttributeRepository extends CrudRepository<Attribute, UUID> {

    List<Attribute> findByLabel(String label);
}
```

For some reason, when under load, some of the REST requests seem to fail with a JDBC exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ATTRIBUTE" not found; SQL statement:
select attribute0_.id as id1_0_0_, attribute0_.description as descript2_0_0_, attribute0_.label as label3_0_0_ from attribute attribute0_ where attribute0_.id=? [42102-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1970) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2827) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2959) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuerySub(Parser.java:2817) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2649) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2620) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:868) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar!/:na]
```

The requests seem to fail arbitrarily, so while a request seems to fail, the next one works just fine, meaning the database is intact and schema initialised correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is an issue that might be related: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2180

Comment: Not sure, but definitely related to a mix of multithreading and H2. Perhaps it's trying to open a second database connection or something... For the time being, I swapped it for HSQLDB which doesn't produce the same sort of error.